# How can I restore original point symbols to highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I've been working with a pretty complex sheet with Highcharts and I'm stuck.

What I have right now is Chart1 allows you to select some points which displays in an HTML table.  If you decide that you don't want those points, I have check boxes that allow "deselection" of the points.

I have another button that deletes the rows of the html table, but I need the other chart to have the symbols "return to normal" that no longer on the html table.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kG2hD/13/

I thought I could do this after I delete the html rows, then replot the selected, but it has no effect:

```
chart.counters.color = 0;
chart.counters.symbol = 0;
chart.redraw();
```

Any ideas on this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advices:

- fix JS errors from console (you are trying to get non existing chart etc.)
- `selectedSamps` contains array of samp-strings from SELECTED points from first chart, when remove tab rows, remove from that array matched samps

I guess it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kG2hD/17/

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if this was a problem with the html table or something to do with the redraw in highcharts.